# Black and white sci-fi show featuring aliens that shoot some kind of beam out of their arm

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

There was a black and white sci-fi show I saw as a kid. All I remember is that the aliens shot some kind of beam out of their arm, but to do so they had to feed it copper. I watched it on daytime tv in the '80s, so it's probably from the '50s, but my Google-fu is weak.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where were you?  US, UK, another European country, etc.?  Any idea what channel you might have been watching?

Comment: Am I the only one who thought "Daleks"?  Until I read the part about the copper...  (although calling that thing an "arm" is a bit of a stretch....)

Comment: And, just to clarify... "they had to feed it copper" -- who had to feed copper to what?  The alien had to feed copper to its own arm?  Had to eat copper?

Comment: DavidW it was in the US, Texas specifically, channel 11 most likely (which was the local station out of Dallas).

Basya The aliens had to stick copper into their arm for it to shoot. I want to say I remember it being a flat stick with symbols on it the aliens used. I think one of the alien arms got cut off and a human (I think child) put copper coins into the slot to shoot the cutoff alien arm. That's the problem with nearly 40 year old memories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That sounds like [Invaders From Mars (1953)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1953_film)) or more likely the remake, [Invaders From Mars (1986)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invaders_from_Mars_(1986_film)), where the Martian drones have laser-like weapons powered by strips of copper.

Near the end of the movie, the protagonist and the soldiers who came to rescue him are trapped in a tunnel as the alien ship is about to explode; the boy finds a penny in his pocket and puts it in the slot of one of the severed weapons to blast a hole to the outside so they can escape.

[image: Martian drone from the 1986 version of Invaders from Mars with beam weapon on shoulder]

[image: Alien claw putting copper stick into the rear slot of a Martian ray gun.]

[image: Boy's hand putting vintage penny into the rear slot of a Martian ray gun]

Note: Both versions were shot in color, which doesn't match your description.

Comment: Typo: "Marsh" (just before 1986)

Comment: @Spencer Thanks! I'll pretend that's the Sean Connery pronunciation.

Comment: That's it exactly. Thank you very much.